# Add new item in list and patch it

Tags: flutter, dart, patch

> I am trying to add a new item in the product_sp and patching it but it results into an exception. This is the response body of product_sp right now- product_sp: [L, test]

```
product_sp.add(newItemPrice);

http.Response response = await client.patch(url,

body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
   "records": [
 {
  "id": orderId,
   "fields": {
  "product_sp": product_sp,
  }
}
   ]
},
));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
 print(data);
} else {
throw Exception();
  }
```

Comment: Do you have the log of the exception? if it is the one you launch, you can also check (and share) what is the response code/message in order to better understand what it is causing the issue

Comment: This is the error that is being generated: I/flutter ( 6545): {error: Invalid payload, details: Error: body.records[0] is not a Record; body.records[0].fields.product_sp is not a CellValue; body.records[0].fields.product_sp is none of number, string, boolean, null, 1 more; body.records[0].fields.product_sp[0] is not a GristObjCode; body.records[0].fields.product_sp[0] is not a valid enum value}